# How to implement a dropdown list like menu when fab is clicked?

Tags: android, floating-action-button

[The video show what the effect i want](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nzze58cxf2fso5b/AACpIOawg8S68SHBY1fCKdZXa?dl=0&preview=ref_5.0%2B6.0_filter.mov)

I have searched github repositories:

> com.hlab.fabrevealmenu
>
> org.zakariya.flyoutmenus
>
> com.shehabic.droppy

but there are no menu meet my requirement...

Anyone can help me? How do i implement the menu?

Comment: you can use PopupWindow

Comment: thanks i'll try it